# How do you create a formula whose output is a BLANK cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, blank

How do you create a formula whose output is a BLANK cell?

Remember a cell whose result is "" is not BLANK.

For example, =ISBLANK(IF(1=1,"","")) results in False.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot. A cell containing a formula will not be blank.  And a formula cannot alter a cell other than the cell where it exists.  You can do it with a VBA macro, but not with a formula.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not acknowledging your assistance at the time I used it.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT. Excel has no way to do this.

As noted in the comment by `Ron Rosenfeld`, you can achieve the idea via VBA. (Of course, through any language Excel will pay attention to.)

That is not, however, Excel doing the thing, it is, say, Javascript doing the thing. And in any case, the formula's output is not a true null, the programming language's action is. (So even when the formula exists only in the program code, its output is not actually a true null, but rather something the programming language takes action because of, said action ending with a true null cell.

This has been a complaint of many for a very long time. Excel's UserVoice site has one main entry about it and endless new posts from folks who don't ever check to see if one already exists.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not acknowledging your assistance at the time I used it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not about the way that the formula outputs real blank, but you could have a look.

If you get the blanks from formulas (**Please note, some formulas do not apply, such as array formulas**), you could choose the cell range, then press Ctrl + F5 to open Find windows.

Then press nothing in Fond what box, look in Values, click Find All.

[image]

And then press Ctrl + A to choose all cells found, close this "Find and Replace" windows. After this step, the  fake empty cells will be selected.

[image]

At last, press Delete key.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not acknowledging your assistance at the time I used it.